# Assign one color per colorbar value

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, colorbar

I have a dataset (agree_all_land) that only contains whole numbers (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). When I plot it, I get the following:
[image]

However, it is unclear which color represents 0 versus 1 for example. I would like each value to have it's own color. That is, in the colorbar there should be six colors (one each for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and the tick for each should be centered to that color. How do I do this?
Here is my code for the plot:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=[10,8])

agree_all_land.topo.plot(cmap='viridis', levels=np.linspace(0,5,6))

axes.set_xlabel('longitude (degrees east)')
axes.set_ylabel('latitude (degrees north)')
```

Comment: What is `agree_all_land.topo.plot`?  This doesn't seem to be standard matplotlib. For 6 color regions, you need 7 borders.  Maybe `levels=np.arange(-0.5,6,1)` would work?  Depending on how `topo.plot` is implemented, you might need to set the colorbar ticks manually (something like `cbar.ax.set_ticks(range(6))` if `cbar` would point to the colorbar).

Comment: topo is just the variable I am selecting from the dataset (agree_all_land) to plot (i.e. it is the same as agree_all_land['topo'].plot(). Thanks I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: So, what type is your "dataset"?  Is this geopandas or some other library?

Comment: The dataset is a netcdf file, opened using xarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

coords = dict(lon=np.arange(360), lat=np.arange(90))
nlon, nlat = len(coords["lon"]), len(coords["lat"])
low, high = 0, 8
ticks = np.arange(low, high + 1)

data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=8, size=(nlon, nlat))

da = xr.DataArray(data, coords=coords)

plot = da.plot.pcolormesh(
    levels=ticks - 0.5,
    cbar_kwargs=dict(ticks=ticks),
)
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for - thanks!